# CoreScanner errors on client

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I have a C# application that uses the CoreScanner.dll and SNAPI API. Everything works fine on my development computer but once I install the application on a client PC it gives a few errors.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {} failed due to the following error: 80080005 or Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80010108.

And if I dont get either of those errors, I can back Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I call one of the scanner methods.

```
try
        {
            try
            {
                cCoreScanner = (CCoreScannerClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CCoreScannerClass));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                using (LogManager lm = new LogManager())
                {
                    lm.WriteErrorTextLog(e, "Setup Scanner - Splash Screen - Scanner Created");
                }
            }

            short[] scannertTypes = new short[1];
            scannertTypes[0] = 1;
            short numberOfScannerTypes = 1;
            int[] connectedScannerList = new int[255];

            try
            {
                cCoreScanner.Open(0, scannertTypes, numberOfScannerTypes, out status);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                using (LogManager lm = new LogManager())
                {
                    lm.WriteErrorTextLog(e, "Setup Scanner - Splash Screen - Scanner Open " + status.ToString());
                }
            }


            try
            {
                cCoreScanner.GetScanners(out numberOfScannerTypes, connectedScannerList, out outXML, out status);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                using (LogManager lm = new LogManager())
                {
                    lm.WriteErrorTextLog(e, "Setup Scanner - Splash Screen - Get Scanners " + status.ToString());
                }
            }

            try
            {
                xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                using (LogManager lm = new LogManager())
                {
                    lm.WriteErrorTextLog(e, "Setup Scanner - Splash Screen - XML Create");
                }
            }

            try
            {
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(outXML);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                using (LogManager lm = new LogManager())
                {
                    lm.WriteErrorTextLog(e, "Setup Scanner - Splash Screen - XML Load");
                }
            }


            try
            {
                scannerID = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("scannerID").Item(0).InnerText;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                using (LogManager lm = new LogManager())
                {
                    lm.WriteErrorTextLog(e, "Setup Scanner - Splash Screen - Get ScannerID");
                }
            }







            try
            {
            cCoreScanner.BarcodeEvent += new _ICoreScannerEvents_BarcodeEventEventHandler(onBarcodeScan);


            inXML = "<inArgs>" +
                    "<scannerID>" + scannerID + "</scannerID>" +
                    "</inArgs>";


            cCoreScanner.ExecCommand(2014, inXML, out outXML, out status);

            opCode = 1001;
            inXML = "<inArgs>" +
                            "<cmdArgs>" +
                            "<arg-int>1</arg-int>" + // Number of events you want to subscribe
                            "<arg-int>1</arg-int>" + // Comma separated event IDs
                            "</cmdArgs>" +
                            "</inArgs>";

            cCoreScanner.ExecCommand(opCode, ref inXML, out outXML, out status);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                using (LogManager lm = new LogManager())
                {
                    lm.WriteErrorTextLog(e, "Setup Scanner - Splash Screen - Enable Scanner, Subscribe to barcode event");
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (LogManager lm = new LogManager())
            {
                lm.WriteErrorTextLog(ex, "Setup Scanner - Splash Screen");
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I have the DLL registered, the SNAPI driver is installed on the client, and I've used the 123Scan utility to set the scanner up for SNAPI input. The client is a Win 7 64 bit, but I've also been testing on a Win XP and getting the same results. Developing on Win 7 32 bit, only difference is my computer as the SDK on it while the others don't.

Update: I finally found the CoreScanner driver on the Motorola website, however the 80010108 error will still happen, but if you restart the application, everything loads fine. Not 100% sure why its failing still but at least it works until the application closes.

Update 2: It seems only to fail after the application is re-installed. After that it will close / open just fine with no errors. Still have no clue has to why it doesn't work the 1st time but at least it works after that.

Comment: Are you running under an account with the same permissions as the account on your dev machine? Also what happens if you copy SDK over?

Comment: They both have administrative rights. I haven't tried switching SDK over yet. Was hoping I wouldn't have to. Will give it a try shortly.